# Problems with the visualization of a report

Tags: jasper-reports

Just like the title said, I have a problem with the visualization of reports with *JasperReports*. Firstly, I am using Eclipse Indigo with the plugin Jaspersoft Studio to create the reports and JDK 1.6 U24.

The following code will help me explain my problem

```
<textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="79" width="423" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#E1E9F0" uuid="9075f7aa-bd0f-4e78-8eca-102cc38f6f37"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="Serif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{inscriptionDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The problem is that the properties of the tags texField and textElement are ignored when the report is displayed, that is, the property "pattern" of the textField tag will be ignored when the variable "inscriptionDate" (Which is of Date type) is displayed in the report. Another example, the "size" and "fontName" properties of the font child tag of the textElement tag, like with textField, this properties are ignored and the text will be show with the default properties.

In the specific case of the "size" property I tried to change the value but I always get the same result. Something funny is that the property "isBold" or "isItalic" aren't ignored.

The same issue happen with the staticText tag:

```
<staticText>
     <reportElement style="titulo2" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="95" width="553" height="12" backcolor="#E1E9F0" uuid="09fb4cfe-831d-42f3-a32c-66ce4a2bc0f0">
         <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
        <font fontName="Serif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[<style size="9">Some text</style>]]></text>
</staticText>
```

The difference between the first code and the second is in the use of the tag `<style>` (second last line), in fact, I am using this "solution" to try to solve my problem but I know that this is not a proper solution.

I really appreciate the help...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's things to be considered.

- **fontName**: When are giving a particular font to a text, that font has to be availabe with `JVM` in order to be applied to the report, If `JVM` doesn't have that font it woud replace it with something which it has (`Arial` in most cases). You would need to create a `Font Extension` for the fonts you require.
- **Formatting date**: The problem here could be report requires `$F{inscriptionDate}` to be in string to format it. However you can alternatively format the date as `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($F{inscriptionDate})`.
- **font size**: font size given to text field must work. There is no scope for a issue here. Try increasing the size considerably to see if it works.

Comment: The two first points have been useful. I tried the last  point several times but it doesn't work: the size of the font appears with the same size in the report, no matter what size was stablished in the property.

Comment: Does this thing happen with this report only or with all other reports as well?

Comment: This happen with all reports.. maybe I'm missing something in the configuration... for this I just install the plugin of Jaspersoft without changing anything and I don't know if I need to follow some configuration steps

Comment: There are no particular configurations required the get the font size fixed. Try a clean build and redeploy your application if it works. Also if you are generating `.jasper` file, delete it and try again.